CLDEMOTE support in intel CPUs
I am new to intel nomenclature, it is not very clear to me which all CPUs support CLDEMOTE instructions.
Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual states that CLDEMOTE supported in

Intel Atom processor based on Tremont microarchitecture, 4th generation Intel® Xeon® Scalable Processor Family based on Sapphire Rapids microarchitecture.

I was under the impression that all hardware after the above stated will have support enabled for CLDEMOTE. But when I run cpuid on a 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-13900KS it gives CLDEMOTE supports cache line demote = false for all CPUs, can someone help me with a list of model names that support CLDEMOTE instruction.
Edit : Followup question is this instruction only supported for E cores ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Cove#Improvements says CLDEMOTE is only supported on the Sapphire Rapids server version of the P cores.  Intel likes to disable features to try to get people to pay more for Xeons.  In desktop/laptop CPUs, it's also disabled on the E cores; there are no CPUs where the E and P cores support different instructions.  That's why your P cores don't support AVX-512 either.

I don't know when/if CLDEMOTE is coming to any Intel mainstream non-Xeon CPUs.  Like I said, disappointing that Intel disables features in some SKUs that use the same silicon.  http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/ has CPUID dumps you can dig through.  The ones with  InstLatX64 benchmarks have decoded CPUID data, but for some CPUs they just have raw hex dumps so you'd have to look up which bit in which sub-leaf is CLDEMOTE and check for it in some new CPUs.

Hi, thanks for the help!!! Was just curious would there be any official documentation present on this. Asking, since manual does not state anywhere about these caveats, though I understand this might not be present due to lack of documentation which is really sad on intel's part

Intel's future-extensions asm manual often indicates which uarch will or did introduce support for upcoming or recent instructions.  But in this case it would have just said Sapphire Rapids and probably not mentioned any client chips (usually with Lake names).  e.g. https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/790021/architecture-instruction-set-extensions-programming-reference.pdf is the 2023 Sep version of it, and indeed just says Tremont and Sapphire Rapids as the introduction point for CLDEMOTE, vs. some other extensions including those plus Alder Lake or Arrow+Lunar Lake.
